# Xamarin.Forms: Scroll effect with collapsing sections of the screen

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm looking for help on how to do this effect:

On a page is a ListView that is 3cm from the top of the page, below a 3cm tall logo. When the user scrolls up the list view, the entire list view scrolls up to take up the 1/2 the space of the logo. Reverse when going down. So basically the Logo gets it's size allocation reduced. Both the logo and the listview can be in a scroll view, but how do I resize the logo

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the answer you placed on another site in case others searching for the solution only come across this article.

```
private const int ScrollMinLimit = 0;
private const int ScrollMaxLimit = 190;
private void ScrollView_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
{
    var val = MathHelper.ReMap(e.ScrollY, ScrollMinLimit, ScrollMaxLimit, 1, 0);

    this.infoPanel.Scale = val;
    this.infoPanel.Opacity = val;
}
```

and

```
public static class MathHelper
{
    public static double ReMap(double oldValue, double oldMin, double oldMax, double newMin, double newMax)
    {
        return (((oldValue - oldMin) / (oldMax - oldMin)) * (newMax - newMin)) + newMin;
    }
}
```